# Trying to access a nested json object inside of an object

Tags: json, object, nested

I've been going at this for a couple hours and I'm about at my wits end.

The data I'm trying to access can either be parsed or stringified, whichever would be easier to code.
Here is the parsed version of the object that I'm trying to access

```
    data: [
    {
      id: '----',
      user_id: '----',
      user_login: '----',
      user_name: '----',
      game_id: '----',
      game_name: '-----',
      type: 'live',
      title: '----',
      viewer_count: -,
      started_at: '----',
      language: 'en',
      thumbnail_url: '----',
      tag_ids: [Array],
      is_mature: false
    }
  ],
  pagination: {}
}
```

The problem I think i'm having is the "data:" at the beginning.

Here's the code that defines this

````
request.get(currentStatus, (err,res,body) => {

        if(err){

            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode)
        
        var data = body

        var id = _.get(body, 'data.id');
        console.log(id)
        
    });```

I really just need to access "id" and define it as its own variable.

Thank's for any advice.
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply parse the response body to a js object, and then access its fields like:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(body);
id = parsed.data[0].id;
```

and if the data array is longer than 1 you can change the index as needed

Comment: part of the issue is this:

`
                id = parsed.data[0].id;
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: can you output the value of `body` at different steps? for example, before and after parsing it? JSON.parse shouldn't return undefined but rather throw an exception if the string can't be parsed, so maybe the data array is missing in the response?

Comment: doing it without parsing leads to this

                id = body.data[0].id;
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: it's not about parsing, it's about making sure that you are receiving the right response, try doing `console.log(body)`, then, if the body is correct, parse it, and then print it again with `console.log(parsed)`. Make sure that whatever you are trying to parse has a `data` attribute, otherwise it will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

You only need to place the index of the array that corresponds to the object you need to access.
var id = data[0].id